В чем разница между free и available полями в выводе команды free?
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        4.9G        143M        7.9M        2.6G        2.4G

Стоит ли мне беспокоиться, что поле free отображает очень мало места? И чем free отличается от available?
